# how to set the userPrincipal() to null in java junit

Tags: struts2, junit4, spring-3

i want to set the UserPrincipal() to null from junit of my application. For that i have tried to set the request to null but i got null pointer exception. Please help me to resolve the problem.
Below is my code

```
if(request.getUserPrincipal()!=null){
     username=request.getUserPrincipal().getName();
}
```

i want to get the condition false.

Comment: How about `request.setUserPrincipal(null);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have found the solution...

get MockHttpServletRequest from junit and set userprinciple to null

```
MockHttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = new MockHttpServletRequest();
httpServletRequest.setUserPrincipal(null);
```